# error: 17892 logon failed for login 'DOMAIN\user' due to trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I developed a .NET program to connect to a SQL Server 2088 Express edition and obtain data. That program runs automatically when Windows starts up, and gives me the error:

> Error code 17892 Logon failed for login 'DOMAIN\user' due to trigger
>   execution. [CLIENTE: local machine]

After searching the internet, I found a few recommendations.  Some said to drop a trigger, but **I don´t have any trigger in my databases**. Others say it is a problem with the user's permissions, but I can access this through SQL Server Management Studio using this user (the Windows user) with no problem.

If I launch my application after opening SQL Server Management Studio the application works fine. If I execute 2 times consecutively, the first fail but the second Works fine.

I configured SQL Server for only Windows authentication, and have the auto_shutdown option of the database off.

This is my connection string:

> "Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress; Initial
>   Catalog=mydb;Trusted_Connection=True;Connection Timeout=150";

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

**EDIT: I PUT ERROR LOG to see login attempts**

```
Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 Login succeeded for user 'DOMAIN\myuser'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENTE: <local machine>]

 Starting up database 'mydb'.
 Error: 17892, gravedad: 20, estado: 1.
Logon failed for login 'DOMAIN\myuser' due to trigger execution. [CLIENTE: <local machine>]
```

Second attempt(this time Works):

```
 Login succeeded for user 'DOMAIN\myuser'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENTE: <local machine>]
 Login succeeded for user 'DOMAIN\myuser'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENTE: <local machine>]
 Login succeeded for user 'DOMAIN\myuser'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENTE: <local machine>]
 Login succeeded for user 'DOMAIN\myuser'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENTE: <local machine>]
 Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2007.100.5500' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_enumerrorlogs'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

And after i log through SSMS:

```
Login succeeded for user 'DOMAIN\myuser'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENTE: <local machine>]
 Login succeeded for user 'DOMAIN\myuser'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENTE: <local machine>]
 Starting up database 'mydb2'.

Login succeeded for user 'DOMAIN\myuser'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENTE: <local machine>]
 Login succeeded for user 'DOMAIN\myuser'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENTE: <local machine>]
 Login succeeded for user 'DOMAIN\myuser'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENTE: <local machine>]
 Attempting to load library 'xplog70.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 Using 'xplog70.dll' version '2007.100.1600' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_msver'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

Comment: Since you can login and access your databases via SSMS, run SELECT * FROM sys.server_triggers to see what logon triggers exist. You can then identify the problematic trigger(s) and fix them or get the owner to fix them. The triggers may serve some important purpose so strongly recommend you figure things out with the creater/owner first. If you can't make progress there and really need to get the app running, you can disable the trigger following instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748.aspx

Comment: Well, i´m sure that the DB don´t have triggers, i created the Data Base, but i do what you suggest and say 0 elements, in addition i go to server objects -->Triggers and the folder is empty.

Thank you for your answer, is good to see that the people answer.

Comment: That is odd. The error is only thrown by logon triggers. Do you see any error in the event log just before the logon trigger errors? Ensure SQL Server logs both successful and failed logins, log into SSMS then run the app until it logs in successfully. Look at what's in sys.dm_exec_sessions after the app logs in. Also check entries in the error log. Finally, check the permissions of your user. You need view definition permissions at the server level to see logon triggers. If you're admin, you already have it, else it needs to be granted explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for answer!!: I´m not very sure where to see the permisions of my user, but i know the user is in the sysadmin group, so i think no problema from here. I´m thinking that perhaps the problema is that in the connection string i put initial catalog=mydb, but i see in SSMS that in my user properties says my default DB is master, is it possible that this is the reason that not fail? I edited the original messege to put there the part of the log renfencing log in attempts, is too long to put in the comments .

When i execute sys.dm_exec_sessions don´t appears any mention of my program